# Get 10 data from API every Load more button click in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angulajs, Initially I need to load first 10 photos after clicking on load more button i need to load another 10 photos.

i have done some work around:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

        app.controller("HttpGetController", function ($scope, $http) {

            $http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1&per_page=6').then(
                function (response) {                   
                    $scope.movies = response.data.data;
                    console.log($scope.movies);
            });

            $scope.loadMore = function() {
               $http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1&per_page=6').then(
                function (response) {                   
                    $scope.movies = response.data.data;
                    console.log($scope.movies);
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: $scope.movies = $scope.movies.concat(response.data.data);

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this. You'll have to keep track which page was retrieved last. You also have to add the new image to the `$scope.movies`.

Here is an example:

```
app.controller("HttpGetController", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.movies = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;

    function load(page, count){
        $http.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=" + page + "&per_page=" + "count").then(
        function (response) { 
            Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.movies, response.data.data);
        });
    }

    load($scope.currentPage++, $scope.itemsPerPage);        

    $scope.loadMore = function() {
       load($scope.currentPage++, $scope.itemsPerPage); 
    }
});
```

As you can see, every time the `load` method is called `$scope.currentPage` is increased by one (`++`). This way, next time `load` is called using this variable as the first argument, the next page is retrieved.

Here, I've used `Array.prototype.push.apply....` to append the items in the HTTP response to the `$scope.movies` array but you could use any other method to append the new items to this array.